# How to insert string of lines and insert each element into different Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

Hi I am trying to make an atom simulation application as my school project. I have created Arrays of each element that I will store like in Atomic number the Atomic number will be stored in Symbol H will be stored and so on. I have read the file using stream reader but i am having difficulty reading each element into the right array.

Txt file is here

```
1,H,Hydrogen,1,1+
3,Li,Lithium,7,1+
11,Na,Sodium,23,1+
19,K,Potassium,39,1+
37,Rb,Rubidium,85,1+
55,Cs,Casesium,133,1+
87,Fr,Francium,223,1+
4,Be,Beryllium,9,2+
12,Mg,Magnesium,24,2+
20,Ca,Calcium,40,2+
38,Sr,Strontium,88,2+
56,Ba,Barium,137,2+
88,Ra,Radium,226,2+
5,B,Boron,10,3+
13,Al,Aluminium,27,3+
31,Ga,Gallium,70,3+
49,In,Indium,115,3+
81,Tl,Thallium,204,3+
6,C,Carbon,12,0
14,Si,Silicon,28,0
32,Ge,Germanium,73,0
50,Sn,Tin,119,0
82,Pb,Lead,207,0
7,N,Nitrogen,14,3-
15,P,Phosphorus,31,3-
33,As,Arsenic,75,3-
51,Sb,Antimony,122,3-
83,Bi,Bismuth,209,3-
8,O,Oxygen,16,2-
16,S,Sulfur,32,2-
34,Se,Selenium,79,2-
52,Te,Tellurium,128,2-
84,Po,Polonium,209,2-
9,F,Fluorine,19,1-
17,Cl,Chlorine,35,1-
35,Br,Bromine,80,1-
53,I,Iodine,127,1-
85,At,Astatine,210,1-
2,He,Helium,4,0
10,Ne,Neon,20,0
18,Ar,Argon,40,0
36,Kr,Kryoton,85,0
54,Xe,Xenon,131,0
86,Rn,Radon,222,0
```

.

```
struct TAtom
{
    public int atomicNumber;
    public string symbol;
    public string name;
    public int mass;
    public string charge;
}

class Atom
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            TAtom[] Atom = new TAtom[44];
            Atom[0].atomicNumber = 1;
            TAtom[] Symbol = new TAtom[44];
            Symbol[1].symbol = "";
            TAtom[] Name = new TAtom[44];
            Name[2].name = "";
            TAtom[] Mass = new TAtom[44];
            Mass[3].mass = '1';
            TAtom[] Charge = new TAtom[44];
            Charge[4].charge = "";

            string[] words;

            StreamReader File = new StreamReader(@"JUNK1.txt");
            while (File.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                string line = File.ReadLine();

                words = line.Split(',');
                 }

            File.Close();   
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you storing all of the values in entirely separate arrays of `TAtom` objects?  Wouldn't each "record" represent a single `TAtom` object?  As for the question being asked, what have you tried?  You're not doing anything with the `words` variable.

Comment: What im trying to do is to get a value from the text file then store it into seperate arrays which correspond to what im looking for. for example i want all my atomic numbers to be stored into Atomic Number, Symbol into Symbols and so on. These arrays can be later used to look up certain values. My techer recommended using struct which I have no idea of using it so I don't know what I'm doing with this code for right now.

Comment: That approach makes no sense.  You should really be building a single `TAtom` instance for each row of data.  Consider as an analogy, storing cars in a parking garage.  Normally, each individual space holds a single and complete car.  What you're doing is having a space for all the steering wheels, a space for all the tires, a space for all the windshields, etc.  And you disassemble each car as it enters the garage, put the components into the spaces, and then plan to re-assemble each car as it leaves the garage.  While it "works", it's fairly inefficient and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

This variable contains the data from a "line" (or "record") in the file:

```
words = line.Split(',');
```

And such a record looks like this:

```
1,H,Hydrogen,1,1+
```

Assuming that the data is consistent (you'd want to add error-checking in a variety of places if it isn't), then you can construct an instance of `TAtom` like this:

```
var atom = new TAtom
{
    atomicNumber = int.Parse(words[0]),
    symbol = words[1],
    name = words[2],
    mass = int.Parse(words[3]),
    charge = words[4]
};
```

Potential runtime errors include, but may not be limited to:

- Invalid `int` data would result in an exception from `int.Parse()`.  Look into the use of `int.TryParse()` as an alternative.  It would require a bit of restructuring of this single line of code into multiple lines, reading inputs separately and constructing the `TAtom` instance at the end.
- Incomplete "records" would result in an exception when attempting to access an invalid index on `words`.  You might check the length of `words` before attempting to use it.

It would be in your best interests to take a look at what your code is doing in a debugger.  As you step through each line of code while it's executing, you can see what's in your variables.  Examining the runtime contents of `words` is your biggest clue on how to construct your `TAtom` instance.

Once you have this instance in the `atom` variable above, you can add that to any array/list/collection/etc. that you like.  (See my comments on the question above regarding your overall design approach.)

Comment: Thank you. I am going to ditch this idea as I have no idea what I'm doing with this anymore but thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

I would read the data in first, as you are doing. Since each line is a TAtom, assign a new TAtom to the appropriate indicies of the comma delimited words(line) array, then add the atom you create for each line to an array or arraylist.

```
List<TAtom> atomList = new List<TAtom>();
StreamReader File = new StreamReader(@"JUNK1.txt");
while (File.EndOfStream == false)
     {
         string line = File.ReadLine();
         TAtom tatom = new TAtom();
         words = line.Split(',');
         tatom.atomicNumber=words[0]
         tatom.symbol=words[1]
         tatom.name=words[2]
         tatom.mass=words[3]
         tatom.charge=words[4]
        //add the current line's atom to a data structure
        atomList.Add(tatom);
   }
   File.Close();
```

Now you can access all of the TAtom structs through the `atomList`!